# Assosiate a request time value to the s:a tag - Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

How can I assosiate a request time value to the **s:a** tag in struts2?

```
<% 
  Object myObj= s.get(0);
%>
<s:a cssStyle="something" href="<%=myObj.toString()%>">
   <%=label%>
</s:a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use scriptlets. The same value you can evaluate via OGNL or JSP EL. The value should be set to the action property and have getter for this.

```jsp
<s:url var="url" value="%{s[0]}"/>
<s:a cssStyle="something" href="%{#url}">
   ${label}
</s:a>
```